# React Context leads to a lot of re-paintings. Is this really a big problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, instagram

Once I asked the question about use of Context/Redux [What to use as global state manager in React NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483194/what-to-use-as-global-state-manager-in-react-nextjs) and got the answer that Context + useReducer is not state manager. I by myself avoid to use Context + useReducer as state manager because it leads to a lot of re-paintings. Is this a big problem? Yesterday I opened an Instagram and opened react-dev-tools (chrome extension) and was surprised that there are a lot of context usage and a lot of re-paintings happens. But it's Instagram a Facebook product. I think these guys know what they are doing. I think that Context is a grate feature
but I try to use it with caution because of extra re-paintings. Can someone to give me solid advise when actually to use Context and when not to use for the sake of optimization question. Can someone to give me some solid resource that will give me more accurate understanding about Context usage. I use Context as property drill solver. But other as state manager. I think that Context robs the app optimization. Different resources tell opposing opinions.

Comment: What kind of answer do you look for? Opinions? Sounds like premature optimization, how we define whats "Big Problem" means

Comment: I just wanted to know is a lot of re-paintings is the problem or not. I want to make a product with higher quality. And keep search solutions and advises from professionals. Unfortunately I could not find a clear answer.

Comment: When I set like on Instagram post the whole page re-paints. But when I make similar functional by myself I make it in the way that re-paints just the place that need to be re-painted  and not the whole page as in Instagram. May be I overdo in optimisations?

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector .